# What kind of SATA connector is this?

Tags: hardware, sata, cable

My Supermicro motherboard has a "vertical S-SATA connector".  The manual simply says "A vertical S-SATA connector, offers four S-SATA 3.0 connections (S-SATA 0-3)".  I took a picture of it and it looks like it has 18 pins.  I've had no luck finding any kind of 18-pin SATA cable.  What kind of connector is this?

[image: c]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Taken from [there](https://www.servethehome.com/sas-sata-cables-guide-sff8087-8088-8470-8482-8484-single-device-connectors/)

> ### SFF-8087 Internal four channel connector (data only)
>
> The SFF-8087 connector is a very widely used connector type that is
>   commonly used today on SAS cards. It carries the equivalent of four
>   SATA/ SAS 7-pin connections through a SFF-8087 to SFF-8087 cable
>   providing 12gbps of throughput using SAS or SATA II 3.0gbps devices.
>
> In fact, many makes of SFF-8087 cables look like four 7-pin cables
>   were sheathed together and terminated at each end by SFF-8087
>   endpoints. SFF-8087 connectors tend to have locking mechanisms that
>   snap into place when a cable  is inserted. This generally keep the
>   connections secure over time even if there is minor chassis movement
>   and vibration.
>
> When purchasing SFF-8087 cables, pay close attention to both ends of
>   the cables. There are many variants which commonly include SFF-8087 to
>   SFF-8087, SFF-8087 to SATA breakout/ four 7-pin connectors, and
>   SFF-8087 to SFF-8088. One needs to ensure they are purchasing the
>   correct cable for their application.

[image: SAS/SATA Backplane with SFF08087 Port]

Comment: Thanks!  I guess what tripped me up is I counted 18 contacts, while it is actually double that-- a 36-pin connector.